# What's this IC marked "DX 802"?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

This is a circuit board for a [set of decoration lights](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B0CHK69STF) that runs on AC.

[image]

The tick marks of the same colour indicate which tracks are connected. The three wires soldered on the top of the board are connected to the series of LEDs.

- There is one IC marked `DX 802` to the right of the capacitor; I am trying to find a datasheet for this. It is a weird IC because it has directly interfaced the AC (follow the blue ticks), as well as half-wave rectified DC via the A7 diode (follow the pink ticks). This seems to be the controller of this board and determines how the series of LED will blink. The entire set is made in China, so I am not sure if any datasheet exists at all.
- There are two components in between the three wires at the top, marked `406`. I think these could be PCR 406 thyristors. Can anyone confirm this? One wire is connected to the top pins of each of these components, and another pin of each is connected to the `DX 802`, so it appears that the controller IC controls the LEDs using these thyristors. However, I did find a [datasheet](https://www.secosgmbh.com/datasheet/products/Silicon_Planar_PNPN_Thyristors/SOT-23/PCR406_PCR606.pdf) of this SMD component, and the pinout is given as follows:

[image]

Why would someone connect the cathode to the controller? Shouldn't it be the gate instead? Or there may be variants in which the cathode and gate pins are interchanged.

The entire circuit seems to be somewhat like this:

[image]

Comment: The manufacturer is possibly `DX Semiconductor (上海典芯半导体有限公司)`. They seem to use the prefix DX for their products and they make LED drivers, like the [DX6210](http://www.kongson.com.cn/uploadfile/201811/20181105025853599.pdf). Beyond that there is not much information available.

Comment: @nanash1 Thanks for some light in the tunnel!